# What is the best practice for maintain a menu after a page reload? I have this custom code which feels wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I have a custom Menu which loads a new MVC View for each click as I want.
I load the new View by setting window.location.href. To make it work I have to set the baseURL (the name of the website) each time. To Store the state of the menu I use URL's querystring.

My concerns is in the use of:

1. '/WebConsole53/' // hardcode baseurl i have to apply each time manually
2. Setting `window.location.href` to load the new View from JavaScript // Is this the best way or should I use some URL/Html helpers instead?
3. I store the state of the selected menuItem in the querystring ("menu") // Is it more common to store that kind in Session/Cookie?

Any thoughts, corrections and suggestions would be much appriciated - thanks.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
var controller = $self.data('webconsole-controller');
var action = $self.data('webconsole-action');
var menu = "?menu=" + $self.attr('id');
var relUrl = controller + "/" + action + menu;
var url = urlHelper.getUrl(relUrl);
window.location.href = url;
```

**UrlHelper.js**

```
var urlHelper = function () {
    var getBaseUrl = '/WebConsole53/',

        buildUrl = function(relUrl) {
            return getBaseUrl + relUrl;
        };

    var getUrl = function(relUrl) { // relUrl format: 'controller/action'
        return buildUrl(relUrl);
    };

    return {
        getUrl: getUrl
    };
}();
```

I Use MVC 5.

Comment: Why not just use `@Html.ActionLink()` to generate links?

Comment: Yea maybe I should do some refactoring and use that. Long story short, I think it started with an ActionLink and other helpers but it wasn't style as I wanted and something else I wasn't satisfied (problably because I didn't knew them well enough) with and then I started to use (to much) JavaScript instead.

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's also the hence I sit with now. Something feels to custom in my code, and I don't have that good MVC code feeling where I use the standards enough. I'm trying to fix it now. I just want to make sure where to put the focus before I start to refactor, which I happily will when I can see an improvement. :)

Comment: Using `ActionLink()` will always generate the correct url and means you don't need any javascript. Not sure what you mean by _" it wasn't style as I wanted"_ (you can use css to style a `<a>` tag to look however you want).  There is no reason to pass a `?menu=` query string to the controller, but without knowing exactly what your trying to do, hard to give any advice.

Comment: 1) yes I had trouble with styling the `<a>` the right way back then. I can solve that now. So I will try refactor that part now. Thanks for convincing me.
2) I use the `?menu=` in the querystring to set the highlight color of the selected menuitem in my menu. e.g. `?menu=dashboard` will highlight the `dashboard`menuitem.

Comment: If the menu item is say 'Login' which directs you to a `Login()` method, that method knows its 'login' - you don't need to pass `?menu=login`

Comment: Yes I have I think, because when i set `window.location.href = ` it forces a reload of the page and the whole menu is being rendered again, hence I lose the highlight.
So far I have writting the whole website with PartialViews to have as less flickering and stuff to render for each call, but know I want more control over the URL, so it's not always the same(good for bookmarks and login), so I guess i am forced to refactor all the PartialViewS to Views. 
Clearly I most be missing some key cencepts to now get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1):

You can save this problem using Route. Through the route you know exactly where you are located in you application.

_Layout.cshtml is definetely not the place to have this javascript. Maybe you are missing some MVC concepts, I would recommend you to read a bit more about routes and routelinks

I hope this helps you a bit: [RouteLinks in MVC](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/03/18/38085/)

Comment: Nice article. I didn't knew about `Html.RouteLink`

Answer (score 1):

> '/WebConsole53/' // hardcode baseurl I have to apply each time manually

sometimes you need to access your root from javascript where you don't have access to server-side code (eg `@Html`).  While refactoring may be the best option you can get around this by storing the baseurl once, using server-side code, eg in _layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var basePath = '@Url.Content("~")';  // includes trailing /
    </script>
    ... load other scripts after the above ...
</head>
```

you can then reference this everywhere and it will always be valid even if you move the base / migrate to test/live.

> Setting window.location.href to load the new View from JavaScript // Is this the best way or should I use some URL/Html helpers instead?

Depends on your requirements - you could use `$.ajax` (or shortcuts `$.get` or `$.load`) to load PartialViews into specific areas on your page.   There's plenty of examples on SO for this and the jquery api help.

Or just use `<a>` anchors or `@Html.ActionLink` as already suggested.   Without needing `menu=` (see next) you don't need to control all your links.

> I store the state of the selected menuItem in the querystring ("menu") // Is it more common to store that kind in Session/Cookie?

If you change the page, then you could query the current url to find which menu item points to it and highlight that one (ie set the menu dynamically rather than store it).

This would also cover the case where you user enters the url directly without the `menu=` part ... or where your forget to add this... not that that would happen :)

**Additional**: You can specify which layout to use in your view by specifying the `Layout` at the top of the view, eg:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/AltLayout.cshtml";
}
```

(which is also one of the options when you right click Views and Add View in visual studio)

Without this, MVC uses a configuration-by-convention and looks at Views/_ViewStart.cshtml which specifies the default _layout.cshtml.

If you don't want a layout at all, then just `return PartialView();` instead

Comment: 1) '@Url.Content("~")' looks VERY interesting, I will give it a go for sure!
2) I know how to use $.ajax and partial views, so far i only use them in the site and i have around 100 of them. The issue is that I can't use $.ajax to solve it all WHEN I ALSO want the URL to change(for bookmarks and so). So far I also only use `return PartialView(model)` in the controllers!
Because of my new URL requirement where it needs to be sat, I am starting to try with Views (`return View(model)`), because they change the URL like I need.
Calling a View reloads the page and the selected Menuitem disappear :(

Comment: Agreed, loading all your content via partialviews is one way to do a single page application (spa).  Not suitable in this case.  Looks like your best bet is for the menu to handle itself - ie the menu sets the selected item based on the current url.  You could do this by adding a property to the menu, eg `data-url='@Url.Action(...` then some js to find the matching menu item each time the menu is rendered.  This puts the onus on the menu rather than your calling pages (and should be more maintainable).

Comment: How does '@Url.Content("~")' work for you? It's a JavaScript string with some C# code the Razor engine can understand. Where or how do you go from JavaScript to using the razor part?

Comment: I have already made an attempt to make the menu self-handeling by  var menu = "?menu=" + $self.attr('id');
                var relUrl = controller + "/" + action + menu;
window.location.href = url;
So when I load a page i save the html element id to the url. and then when the _Layout.cshtml re load I set the highlighted menuitem by 
        var menuId = getMenuIdFromQueryString();
        if (menuId !== "") {
            $('#' + menuId).addClass('selected'); // navReports
        }

I am just mind boggled whether it's is right or wrong to load the _Layout each time.

Comment: `'@Url.Content("~")` will be replaced server-side as part of the Razor processing, so you'll get `var basePath='http://host/path/siteroot'` in the html which will run as js as it's in a `script` tag

Comment: _layout will always be loaded when you return `View()` and not when you return `PartialView()` (this can be changed, but it's the default operation)

Comment: I must have misunderstood you the first time. I simply just tryed to replace this in my eager:
    var getBaseUrl = '@Url.Content("~")',
//    var getBaseUrl = '/WebConsole53/',

Comment: Can you UPDATE your answer with and example how to avoid to load the _Layout when returning `View()`? I really appreciate your answers alot man